# Parameter prefix in Vue.js route path

Tags: javascript, routes, vue.js, vue-router

tl;dr:

In Vue.js `vue-router`, how can we make a route `param` immediately follow a non-`/` character and still be resolved?

--

*Explanations*

I want some urls to look like:

```
example.com/_myuser
example.com/_otheruser
```

In Flask this could be done the following way:

```
@app.route('/_<username>')
def user_page(username):
    pass

print(url_for('user_page', username='myuser'))
# example.com/_myuser
```

But I can't find a way to make this work in `vue-router`. When I try:

```
router.map({
    '/_:username': {
        name: 'user-page',
        component: User
    }
})
```

The `username` param won't resolve at all (nor in the templates, nor when typed in the browser's address bar):

```
<a v-link="{ name: 'user-page', params: { username: 'myUser' } }">Hello</a>

expected      <a href="/_myUser">Hello</a>
result        <a href="/_:username">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In vue 1.* this isn't possible but in 2.0 this can be done by using `/(@):username`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: what I'm asking for is not possible today in `vue-router`.

See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/499 for the related GitHub issue, and a possible way to implement this functionality.

Comment: @rafaelmsantos well, this answer is not a complement to the question, it really serves an an answer, like "is it possible? -> no, that's not possible for the moment".